# Фигурный фиолетовый фон

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребят, на фону фиолетовая фигура. Видел сервисы типа GetWaves, но там либо волна сверху, либо снизу, такой двусторонней нет. Помогите, пожалуйста, с вариантами, как делать, либо ссылки на сервисы.

Comment: svg или изображение.

Comment: Задай как background-image... в чем проблема задавать ее как что то отдельное